# If G is a finite group and solvable, it has a composition series

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, solvable-groups

Given a finite solvable group G, my teacher just used the fact that it has a composition series. I don't see why it's immediate, or even necessarily true.

If $(G_0={e} ,G_1,...,G_n=G)$ is the normal series because of which G is solvable, we have by definition that $\forall 0\leq i\leq n-1$ that $G_{i+1}/G_i$ is abelian, meaning every subgroup is normal. But it doesn't mean that $G_{i+1}/G_i$ is simple as we'd like.

Notation might be weird (I think it's mostly noted the other way around) but that's how it was defined in my class, so excuse me if it's confusing.

Comment: You mean "simple as we'd like"? It doesn't matter whether a group is solvable or not. A finite group always has a composition series. And solvable groups additionally have composition series with every quotient abelian simple (meaning $\mathbb{Z}_p$).

Comment: Do finite abelian groups have a composition series? If so, then you are done.

Comment: Yes, I meant "simple" (edited it for clarification). I will prove to myself that every finite group has a composition series, and that should be enough then. Thank you!

Comment: @M_N1 for that you need the following two facts: (1) every finite group has a (proper) maximal normal subgroup and (2) given a finite group $G$ and a non-trivial  normal subgroup $H$ we have $|G/H|<|G|$. Both together with induction on $|G|$ imply that every finite group has a composition series.

Comment: Every finite group has a composition series has many proofs here already (see the duplicates).